# Don't you bulge?

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

In the movie *Some Like It Hot* (1959) when Jerry who was pretending to be a girl was walking down the aisle on train to settle in his seat, some girl told him to take off his corset and spread out. Jerry said in response that he doesn't wear one himself. The girl kind of surprised by that said, '**Don't you bulge?**' Does she mean doesn't your stomach stick out? If yes, considering the movie was made almost 70 years ago, would an English native speaker say it this way or use a different expression to mean that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose a more modern-day equivalent of '*Don't you bulge?*' would be

> Don't you have **a belly**?

The woman's soft, sensual, round belly, beloved and immortalized by artists such as Rubens and Titian has surrendered, for some time, to the very flat and tight      *[washboard stomach](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/washboard-stomach)* or the [six-pack](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/six-pack) abs.

On the other hand, a **pooch belly** can be quite attractive. The *[Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pooch%20belly)* provides a work-safe definition which I rather like

> Region of a females lower stomach that appears as fat around the belly button and has little or no lovehandles. Women sometimes develop one after childbirth even if they are skinny. Other women develop one from age or lack of exercise which is normal and affects all bodytypes in varying degrees. Can make some women look more desireable even if they feel the opposite or try to cover it up. **Also known as a *pooch***.
>   Lucy was always slim until she had her baby and now she has the cutest pooch belly.

Apparently, the term has been in use since at least 2009.

[image]

Source: *[Swimsuits to hide Belly Pooch 2017](https://bathing-suits.info/swimsuits-to-hide-belly-pooch-2017/)*

Comment: I remember our ob/gyn using this term in 2003 to describe a pregnant belly!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say 'Don't you bulge?' It does sound old-fashioned; it might have been intended as comical even in the movie. The word *[bulge](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bulge)* itself is still a usable verb (and noun) today, and there is a common idiom related to reducing weight (see below). My friends don't wear corsets, and I don't know anybody who does. So it's not easy to think of an equivalent. Something like 'Won't you stick out?' doesn't seem appropriate. If it is someone you know really well, you might be able to say *Won't that make you look overweight?*

If someone is on a weight-reducing diet, he or she can readily use [the idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/battle+of+the+bulge) *I'm fighting 'the battle of the bulge'.* Here, *bulge* refers to that part of the body which shows the quality of "fatness" (and that can differ from person to person, but can include the stomach, thighs, buttocks). This idiom is a [takeoff](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/takeoff) (definition 2) of the name of the World War 2 campaign called [the battle of the Bulge](http://www.historynet.com/battle-of-the-bulge). See also [History dot com](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/battle-of-the-bulge).

Comment: Also, "bulge" is itself a funny-sounding word.